# How to know if python script was run using interpreter's -m option?

Tags: python, command-line

I couldn't find answer after having read all the following:

- [PEP 338 Executing modules as scripts](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0338/)
- [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/runpy.html) of `runpy` standard module
- [description](http://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html) of Python interpreter's `-m` option

Rationale:
When a test script which uses relative imports is being run without `-m` option I could print a warning message instead of leaving user with standard traceback leading to `ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package` exception. Without knowing this I can catch this exception and only **suggest** lack of `-m` option could be the reason of error.

Comment: What do you need it for? Could you give some example or a test case in which this need becomes apparent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another observation is that `__package__` is set to `None` when executing the script directly and to the package name when using `-m` (using the empty string when the module isn't included in any package, so it's still different from `None`).

Comment: Nice! It's not only observation as this is **mandated** by [PEP 366 Main module explicit relative imports](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0366/).

Answer (score 3):

Disclaimer: this is just an observation, I have not seen it in the docs so it is probably implementation dependent and might not be consistent across different Python versions.

I have noticed that when calling a script using a `-m` option a variable called `__loader__` is added to the namespace, so at the top of your script you could check for existence of that variable:

```
if '__loader__' in globals():
    # called with -m
```

For some extra safety you could check to see if `__loader__` is an instance of `pkgutil.ImpLoader`:

```
if '__loader__' in globals() and __loader__.__class__.__name__ == 'ImpLoader':
```

Comment: This **is** in the docs of `runpy` module; *The special global variables `__name__`, `__file__`, `__loader__` and `__package__` are set in the globals dictionary before the module code is executed (Note that this is a minimal set of variables - other variables may be set implicitly as an interpreter implementation detail).* However `__loader__` is kind of generic and we never know what else might set it someday...

Comment: @RaymondHettinger Is there any reason there's no really **unique** global variable set in this situation?

Comment: The only guaranteed unique variables are *None* and \_\_debug\_\_; however, any double underscored name is treated as reserved for creation by core developers, so \_\_loader\_\_ is somewhat safe (or at least as safe as ``__name__=='__main__'``).  If it keeps you up at night, it is alway possible to introspect the object to validate the match.

Comment: I'm curious why you didn't use `isinstance`?

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost - `pkgutil.ImpLoader` is not a part of the namespace, it would need to be imported first.  That is another option though.