# Python doesn't seem to like the name "site"?

Tags: python

I have two files, lattice.py and site.py in the same directory.

lattice.py

```
from site import Site
class Lattice:
    <stuff>
```

site.py

```
import random
class Site:
    <stuff>
```

But when I try to run lattice.py, I get a "cannot import name Site" error. However, if I rename site.py to banana.py and change the code accordingly, everything works out. What's wrong with the file name "site"?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/site.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @MartijnPieters has indicated, there is already a `site.py` automatically imported.

The problem is that your `site.py` is conflicting with Python's `site.py` (your `site.py` is not imported by `from site import Site` and there is no `Site` class in python's `site.py`).

The solution is to change the name of that file to something else (as you've already experienced), or to suppress the auto-import using the interpreter’s -S option (as indicated in [@MartijnPieters link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/site.html)).

Answer (score 3):

(The other answer/s already explain why an error is raised, so not repeating it here)

In general, it is safer and more recommended to use relative imports:

```
from .site import Site
```

You may also consider adding the "absolute_import" directive (if using python 2.x):

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
```

More info about absolute/relative imports in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616952/how-to-properly-use-relative-or-absolute-imports-in-python-modules).