# Function import from parent folder issue

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have folder structure like this:

```
d1
 - app
   — script.py
 - lib
   — lib1
     — file.py
```

When I do `from ..lib.lib1 import my func` in `script.py` it gives error:

```
SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import
```

I am using Python 3.

Comment: You could find that page by pasting the error message in any decent search engine.

Comment: @vaultah and what made you to think  I did not try it? I did try but some how I am doing something wrong that it still gives error.

Comment: `from ..lib.lib1 import my func` produces a `SyntaxError`. What is your actual `import` statement? It also appears the you're trying to import from a grandparent folder, not the parent folder.

Comment: Relative imports only work inside Python packages. Your folder structure doesn't define one. Question [**_How to properly use relative or absolute imports in Python modules?_**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616952/how-to-properly-use-relative-or-absolute-imports-in-python-modules) may help.

Comment: Also see the documentation about regular [**Packages**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#packages).

Comment: @martineau correct, from garandparent folder.

Answer (score 0):

Relative imports are for use within packages. You could change what you have into one by adding some empty `__init__.py` files into your directory structure like this:

```
d1
 - test.py  # added to run script.py below
 - app
   - __init__.py  # an empty script
   — script.py
 - lib
   - __init__.py  # an empty script
   — lib1
     - __init__.py  # an empty script
     — file.py
```

There's also a new file I've called `test.py` because you genrally can't run modules within a package as the main script (which is why I added  `test.py`). All it contains is:

```
from app import script
```

I also changed the import in `script.py` to this:

```
from lib.lib1 import file
```

To show that the above `import` works, I put a `print('in file.py')` in `file.py`.

Now running `test.py`, which runs the `script` module by importing it, produces the following output:

```
in file.py
```

Now, if you want to import a particular function from `file.py`, you could do something like this in `script.py`:

```
from lib.lib1.file import my_func
```

Comment: The real case to use is for CRON JObs.

Comment: Whatever—shouldn't matter.