# Attempted relative import in non-package (after 2to3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2to3

After converting to Python 3.x using `2to3` (see my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497013/convert-code-from-python-2-x-to-3-x/5497070#5497070)), I get this error during the build:

```
  File "setup.py", line 28, in <module>
    from . import mof_compiler
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

The code:

```
from . import mof_compiler
mof_compiler._build()
```

But I don’t know why this is wrong, since `mof_compiler` is in the same dir as `setup.py`. Please help!

Comment: Duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226893/understanding-a-chain-of-imports-in-python http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112618/import-python-package-from-local-directory-into-interpreter http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585756/python-do-relative-imports-mean-you-cant-execute-a-subpackage-by-itself

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since there is no `__init__.py`, the working directory is a non-package.

You don't need a relative import.

Or.

You need an `__init__.py` to make a package.

Comment: so change it to just import mof_compiler is ok?

Comment: @Remko: But I believe the answer to your question is No, since implicit relative imports are now strongly discouraged. I believe the explicit equivalent (which is still relative) is this: from . import mof_compiler

Comment: my folder already has `__init__.py` and I'm having the same error

Comment: This answer is incomplete: `mkdir /tmp/pymodtest; cd /tmp/pymodtest; touch __init__.py a.py; echo "from . import a" > b.py; python2 b.py` yields the same error, though clearly a `__package__` file is present.