# Importing relative packages for testing

Tags: python, import, module, package

I developed a solution with the following structure:

```
my_package/
my_test_data/
test.py
```

In `test.py`I can easily import my_package (`from my_package import my_class`). This is very useful in my IDE of choice where I can write test cases, execute them and eventually set breakpoints in the code being tested where needed.

The fine structure, ready for distribution, changed to:

```
my_package/
tests/
    my_test_data/
    test.py
```

This is ok if someone wants to test that what's been installed works fine. Test references the installed version of my_package. The problem is that during development I need to reference `my_package` from the development folder, so that I can test the live version I'm developing and eventually step into it for debugging purposes. I tried to solve the problem with relative import `from .my_package import my_class`, `from .. my_package import my_class` and other combinations but I get this Exception:

```
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume that the development structure is under `/dev` and the distribution structure is under `/install`.

Note that, by default, [sys.path](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.path) has the script directory as its first entry.  So, if `test.py` has an `import my_package` statement and you run `/dev/test.py`, it should find `my_package`, even if your `$PYTHONPATH` is empty.  If `/install` is the first entry in `$PYTHONPATH`, then running `/install/tests/test.py` should find `/install/my_package` for `import my_package`.

Summary: have you tried using `import my_package` in `test.py` and including `/install` in your `$PYTHONPATH`?

Answer (score 0):

Relative imports are only allowed intra-packages wise. You mustn't confuse directory-references with package-handling.

Proposed solutions on a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9732047/1107807).

Comment: thanks! but, in my example, i tried to sys.path.append('..') or sys.path.append('../') but from my_package import my_class still picks the installed one