# How to fix "Attempted relative import in non-package" even with __init__.py

Tags: python, package, python-import, importerror, init

I'm trying to follow [PEP 328](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/), with the following directory structure:

```
pkg/
  __init__.py
  components/
    core.py
    __init__.py
  tests/
    core_test.py
    __init__.py
```

In `core_test.py` I have the following import statement

```
from ..components.core import GameLoopEvents
```

However, when I run, I get the following error:

```
tests$ python core_test.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "core_test.py", line 3, in <module>
    from ..components.core import GameLoopEvents
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

Searching around I found "[relative path not working even with __init__.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9427037/relative-path-not-working-even-with-init-py)" and "[Import a module from a relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279237/python-import-a-module-from-a-folder/6098238#6098238)" but they didn't help.

Is there anything I'm missing here?

Comment: I was also very confused by the various ways of structuring `unittest` projects, so I wrote this [fairly exhaustive sample project](https://github.com/cod3monk3y/PyImports) that covers deep nesting of modules, relative and absolute imports (where the work and don't), and relative and absolute referencing from within a package, as well as single, double, and package-level import of classes. Helped clear things *right up* for me!

Comment: I could not get your tests to work. Keep getting `no module named myimports.foo` when I run them.

Comment: @Blairg23 I'm guessing the intended invocation is to `cd` into `PyImports`, and run `python -m unittest tests.test_abs`, for example.

Comment: I agree with Gene.  I wish there was a mechanism for debugging the importing process that was a little more helpful.

In my case, I have two files in the same directory.  I am trying to import one file into the other file.  If I have an __init__.py file in that directory, I get a ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package error.  If I remove the __init__.py file, then I get an error no module named 'NAME' error.

Comment: In my case, I have two files in the same directory.  I am trying to import one file into the other file.  If I have an __init__.py file in that directory, I get a ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package error.  If I remove the __init__.py file, then I get an error no module named 'NAME' error.

What is really frustrating is that I had this working, and then I shot myself in the foot by deleting the .bashrc file, which set the PYTHONPATH to something, and now it is not working.

Comment: @user1928764: These errors are indeed frustrating. I assume you meant "`__init__.py` file."

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14132912/11573842

Answer (score 475, accepted):

Yes. You're not using it as a package.

```
python -m pkg.tests.core_test
```

Comment: A gotcha: Note that there is no '.py' at the end!

Comment: I'm not either of the downvoters, but I feel this could use *quite a bit* more detail, given the popularity of this question and answer. Noting stuff like from what directory to execute the above shell command, the fact that you need `__init__.py`s all the way down, and the `__package__`-modifying trickery (described below by BrenBarn) needed to allow these imports for executable scripts (e.g. when using a shebang and doing `./my_script.py` at the Unix shell) would all be useful. This whole issue was quite tricky for me to figure out or find concise and understandable documentation on.

Comment: There is a [nicely elaborated recent answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27876800/838992) with a link to the docs as suggested by the upvoted comment.

Comment: Note: you need to be outside of the directory `pkg` at the point where you call this line from the CLI. Then, it should work as expected. If you are inside `pkg` and you call `python -m tests.core_test`, it will not work. At least it didn't for me.

Comment: This does not work if you run the script inside components dir for example

Comment: I coupled this with `cd`ing into the project's parent directory. `cd /path/to/project && python -m project.module.submodule`. You may want to add `&& cd ~` in the end if you are testing this out multiple times on local system.

Comment: When they designed the language, why didn't they just make "python pkg/test/core_test.py" do the same thing as "python -m pkg.test.core_test"?   Why do they deliberately break relative imports whenever you run anything as a script?

Comment: @JonathanRay: Because having them do the same thing makes execution ambiguous; what sense does it make for `python /usr/share/someapp/somescript.py` to be `usr.share.someapp.somescript`?

Comment: Seriously, can you explain whats going on in your answer?

Comment: @MarkAmery Almost lost my mind trying to grok how all this works, relative imports within a project with subdirectories with py files that have `__init__.py` files yet you keep getting the `ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package` error. I would pay really good money for someone, somewhere, to finally explain in plain English how all of this works.

Comment: Contrary to the answer for an FAQ in Python this answer gives  no clue what is happening and from where to execute this command

Comment: for running on jupyter notebook %run <filename/path> -m

Comment: I'm not sure how running it as a module helps @skytreader 's import problem from within another script...

Comment: Maybe I don't really understand the cultural norms around the wiki-like features on SO, but it's notable that no one pointing out how Ignacio's answer could be improved actually improved it in-place. (Mind you, I agree 100% with the comments that an explanation would be extremely helpful.)

Comment: `-m` flag is used to run the file as a script. It indicates the module name and starts from the parent module and goes deeper in the directory to run the script.

Comment: What does the answer actually mean?

Comment: @Philip Probably because no one actually knows how or why it works? That's the reason people want OP to add detail to the answer. If people already knew the details, they wouldn't need OP to add the detail themselves.

Comment: @Nevermore -- fair point. My perception is probably biased slightly by my observation people seem generally slow to view the questions as wiki-like. And I don't want to start riding roughshod over cultural norms.

Comment: @Philip part of the problem is that answers (and questions) accumulate reputation for the original author over time, which isn't shared by editors. Even if it were, there wouldn't be a tractable way to assess how much of the credit should go to each participant. There are some norms around authorial intent, but I honestly think people are *mainly* held back by a poor incentive structure.

Comment: this works but not when using pytest :(

Answer (score 686):

To elaborate on [Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11536794/5337834) answer:

The Python import mechanism works relative to the `__name__` of the current file.  When you execute a file directly, it doesn't have its usual name, but has `"__main__"` as its name instead.  So relative imports don't work.

You can, as Igancio suggested, execute it using the `-m` option.  If you have a part of your package that is meant to be run as a script, you can also use the `__package__` attribute to tell that file what name it's supposed to have in the package hierarchy.

See http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0366/ for details.

Comment: Took a while for me to realize you can't run `python -m core_test` from within the `tests` subdirectory - it has to be from the parent, or you have to add the parent to the path.

Comment: So can I therefore use __package__ to ensure executable script files are able to relative import from the rest of the system regardless of their level in the hierarchy? This would be very useful indeed.

Comment: @DannyStaple: Not exactly.  You can use `__package__` to ensure executable script files can relatively import other modules from within the same package.  There's no way to relatively import from "the whole system".  I'm not even sure why you'd want to do this.

Comment: I mean if the `__package__` symbol is set to "parent.child" then you'd be able to import "parent.other_child". Perhaps I didn't phrase it so well.

Comment: @DannyStaple: Well, how it works is described in the linked documentation.  If you have a script `script.py` in package `pack.subpack`, then setting it's `__package__` to `pack.subpack` will let you do `from ..module import something` to import something from `pack.module`.  Note that, as the documentation says, you still have to have the top-level package on the system path.  This is already the way things work for imported modules.  The only thing `__package__` does is let you use that behavior for directly-executed scripts as well.

Comment: There is no sample code in the PEP-0366 linked documentation @BrenBarn. Where can I find sample code?

Comment: @AlisonS: Sample code to do what?  There is a small snippet in the PEP that explains how to set `__package__`.

Comment: But there is no context to where that snippet belongs @BrenBarn. Does it go in the file you're importing? In the file that is doing the import? Where in the relevant file does it go?

Comment: @AlisonS: It says right there: "To allow relative imports when the module is executed directly, boilerplate similar to the following would be needed before the first relative import statement".  I think that is pretty clear that you put it in the module you are executing directly, before that module attempts any relative imports.

Comment: I use `__package__` in the script which is executed directly but Unfortunately, I get the the following error: "Parent module 'xxx' not loaded, cannot perform relative import"

Comment: @AramKocharyan aside from hacking the path within the script, it should also work to set the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable appropriately.

Answer (score 230):

It depends on how you want to launch your script.

If you want to [launch your UnitTest from the command line](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html) in a classic way, that is:

```
python tests/core_test.py
```

Then, since in this case *'components'* and *'tests'* are siblings folders, you can import the relative module either using the *insert* or the *append* method of the *[sys.path](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.path)* module.
Something like:

```
import sys
from os import path
sys.path.append( path.dirname( path.dirname( path.abspath(__file__) ) ) )
from components.core import GameLoopEvents
```

Otherwise, you can [launch your script with the '-m' argument](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m) (note that in this case, we are talking about a package, and thus you must not give the *'.py'* extension), that is:

```
python -m pkg.tests.core_test
```

In such a case, you can simply use the relative import as you were doing:

```
from ..components.core import GameLoopEvents
```

You can finally mix the two approaches, so that your script will work no matter how it is called.
For example:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    if __package__ is None:
        import sys
        from os import path
        sys.path.append( path.dirname( path.dirname( path.abspath(__file__) ) ) )
        from components.core import GameLoopEvents
    else:
        from ..components.core import GameLoopEvents
```

Comment: what shall i do if i am trying to use the pdb for debugging? since you use `python -m pdb myscript.py` to launch the debugging session.

Comment: @dannynjust -- That's a good question since you can't have 2 main modules.  Generally when debugging, I prefer to drop into the debugger manually at the first point where I want to start debugging.  You can do that by inserting a `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` into the code (inline).

Comment: Is it better to use `insert` instead of `append`? That is, `sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))`

Comment: Using insert is a better match for the relative import semantics, where local package names take precedence over installed packages. Especially for tests, you usually want to test the local version, not the installed one (unless your test infrastructure installs the code under test, in which case relative imports are unneeded and you won't have this problem).

Comment: you should also mention that you can't be in the directory containing core_test when you run as a module (that would be too easy)

Answer (score 213):

You can use `import components.core` directly if you append the current directory to `sys.path`:

```
if __name__ == '__main__' and __package__ is None:
    from os import sys, path
    sys.path.append(path.dirname(path.dirname(path.abspath(__file__))))
```

Comment: `sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..')))` this will also work

Comment: `from os import sys` looks like cheating :)

Comment: @ajay And yours is better because of what?

Comment: @Piotr: It's might be considered better because it slightly shows more clearly what is being being appended to `sys.path` -- the parent of the directory the current file is in.

Comment: @martineau I think you are [right](https://github.com/pfmoore/pip/commit/87418e05bb55ea64476653dd41e2f4db785f02c0#commitcomment-5418772) :)

Comment: @Piotr: Ah, yes, I would have to agree that  `sys.path.append(path.dirname(path.dirname(__file__)))` would be even more clear -- and with a comment, perfect.

Comment: @flyingsheep: Agreed, I'd just use a regular `import sys, os.path as path`.

Comment: FYI, to use this in an ipython notebook, I adapted this answer to: `import os; os.sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath('.')))`. Then a straight `import components.core` works for me, importing from the notebook's parent directory as desired.

Comment: Great things for nested usage of `dirname` function. Haven't seen that before.

Comment: How does `from os import sys` work? `os` is a module outside the `sys` module.

Comment: May I add another trick... I tried every advise that I could find on SO regarding a similar issue and finally found that I had some old .pyc files that were causing conflicts. So if anyone tries the above solution and it fails, check if you need to delete your .pyc files.

Comment: doing sys.path.append is not cool to do because generating a standalone installer with pyinstall... fails miserably. I switched to file system links

Answer (score 34):

**In core_test.py, do the following:**

```
import sys
sys.path.append('../components')
from core import GameLoopEvents
```

Answer (score 14):

The issue is with your testing method.

You tried `python core_test.py` and then you will get this error:

> ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package

Reason: you are testing your packaging from a non-package source.

So test your module from the package source.

If this is your project structure,

```
pkg/
  __init__.py
  components/
    core.py
    __init__.py
  tests/
    core_test.py
    __init__.py
```

**cd pkg**

```
python -m tests.core_test # dont use .py
```

**or from outside pkg/**

```
python -m pkg.tests.core_test
```

single `.` if you want to import from a folder in the same directory.
For each step back, add one more.

```
hi/
  hello.py
how.py
```

In `how.py`

```
from .hi import hello
```

in case if you want to import how from *hello.py*:

```
from .. import how
```

Comment: In the example `from .. import how`, how do you import a specific class / method from the 'how' file. when I do the equivalent of `from ..how import foo` then I get "attempted relative import beyond top-level package"

Comment: @JamesHulse Does `from .. import how` work but the second statement not? I would have assumed that both statements won't work, if the folder that contains the hi folder does not contain an _ _ init _ _.py file. In other words, if there is only an init file in the hi folder, then the hi folder is the top level package and you cannot address beyond it.

Answer (score 11):

If your use case is for running tests, and it seams that it is, then you can do the following. Instead of running your test script as `python core_test.py` use a testing framework such as `pytest`. Then on the command line you can enter

```
$$ py.test
```

That will run the tests in your directory. This gets around the issue of `__name__` being `__main__` that was pointed out by @BrenBarn. Next, put an empty `__init__.py` file into your test directory, this will make the test directory part of your package. Then you will be able to do

```
from ..components.core import GameLoopEvents
```

However, if you run your test script as a main program then things will fail once again. So just use the test runner. Maybe this also works with other test runners such as `nosetests` but i haven't checked it. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 9):

My quick-fix is to add the directory to the path:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '../components/')
```

Comment: Your approach wont work in all cases because '../' part is resolved from directory from which you run your script(core_test.py). With your approach you are forced to cd to 'tests' before running the core_test.py scritp.

Answer (score 7):

As you have already marked everything as a module, there isn't any need to use the relative reference if you launch it as a Python module.

Instead of

```
from ..components.core import GameLoopEvents
```

simply

```
from pkg.components.core import GameLoopEvents
```

When you run from the parent of the package, use the following:

```
python -m pkg.tests.core_test
```

Comment: Nice! I was having trouble testing my package using this style of imports because python would pick up an older, installed, version of my package rather than the new version I was testing. That's when running as python pkg/tests/core_test.py or similar. But using -m solves this, seems to now prefer the local copy, I guess because it is considered a module now. Kind of makes me wonder when relative imports are ever a good idea though...

Answer (score 4):

As [Paolo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11536764/how-to-fix-attempted-relative-import-in-non-package-even-with-init-py/27876800#27876800) said, we have two invocation methods:

1. `python -m tests.core_test`
2. `python tests/core_test.py`

One difference between them is the *sys.path[0]* string. Since [the interpret will search *sys.path* when doing import](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/sys.html), we can do with `tests/core_test.py`:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    from pathlib import Path
    sys.path.insert(0, str(Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent))
    from components import core
    <other stuff>
```

And more after this, we can run *core_test.py* with other methods:

```
cd tests
python core_test.py
python -m core_test
...
```

Note, tested only on Python 3.6.

Answer (score 3):

I found out that adding an `__all__= ['submodule', ...]` to the
****init**.py** file and then using the `from <CURRENT_MODULE> import *` in the target works fine.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `from pkg.components.core import GameLoopEvents`. For example, I use [PyCharm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JetBrains#IDEs).

The below is my project structure image. I just import from the root package, and then it works:

[image]

Comment: This did not work for me. Did you have to set the path in your configuration?

Comment: @MohammadMahjoub You need all the init files that he also has to make this work... Don't forget the one in cnn_scratch

Answer (score 3):

This approach worked for me and is less cluttered than some solutions:

```
try:
  from ..components.core import GameLoopEvents
except ValueError:
  from components.core import GameLoopEvents
```

The parent directory is in my PYTHONPATH, and there are `__init__.py` files in the parent directory and this directory.

The above always worked in Python 2, but Python 3 sometimes hit an ImportError or ModuleNotFoundError (the latter is new in Python 3.6 and a subclass of ImportError), so the following tweak works for me in both Python 2 and Python 3:

```
try:
  from ..components.core import GameLoopEvents
except ( ValueError, ImportError):
  from components.core import GameLoopEvents
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
import components
from components import *
```

Answer (score 2):

### `python <main module>.py` does not work with relative import

The problem is [relative import](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/#relative-imports-and-name) does not work when you run a `__main__` module from the command line

```
python <main_module>.py
```

It is clearly stated in [PEP 338](https://staging.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0338/#import-statements-and-the-main-module).

> The release of 2.5b1 showed a surprising (although obvious in retrospect) interaction between this PEP and PEP 328 - **explicit relative imports don't work from a main module**. This is due to the fact that relative imports rely on `__name__` to determine the current module's position in the package hierarchy. In a main module, the value of `__name__` is always `'__main__'`, so **explicit relative imports will always fail** (as they only work for a module inside a package).

### Cause

- [Python Bug Tracker Issue1510172: Absolute/relative import not working?](https://bugs.python.org/issue1510172)

> The issue isn't actually unique to the -m switch. The problem is that relative imports are based on `__name__`, and in the main module, `__name__` always has the value `__main__`. Hence, **relative imports currently can't work properly from the main module of an application**, because **the main module doesn't know where it really fits in the Python module namespace** (this is at least fixable in theory for the main modules executed through the -m switch, but directly executed files and the interactive interpreter are completely out of luck).

To understand further, see [Relative imports in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28154841/4281353) for the detailed explanation and how to get it over.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a workaround.  Here's a bit of context.  I wanted to test out one of the methods I've in a file.  When I run it from within

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
```

it always complained of the relative imports.  I tried to apply the above solutions, but failed to work, since there were many nested files, each with multiple imports.

Here's what I did.  I just created a launcher, an external program that would import necessary methods and call them.  Though, not a great solution, it works.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way which will piss off everyone, but it works pretty well. In tests, run:

```
ln -s ../components components
```

Then just import components like you normally would.

Comment: This is a seriously undervalued gem! I can't understand why there are not enough up-votes to make this answer near the top!

Answer (score 1):

For me only this worked: I had to explicitly set the value of **package** to the parent directory, and add the parent directory to sys.path

```
from os import path
import sys
if __package__ is None:
    sys.path.append( path.dirname( path.dirname( path.abspath(__file__) ) ) )
    __package__= "myparent"

from .subdir import something # the . can now be resolved
```

I can now directly run my script with `python myscript.py`.

Answer (score 1):

If your project structure would look like this:

```
   project
     |
     | --- module1
     |      |
     |      file1.py
     |
     |-----module2
     |     |
     |     file2.py
```

and you are going import file1.py from within file2.py,
you can do this in file2.py:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('.')

import file2
```

I still don't know why and how, but it worked for me.

Comment: Are sure it is not `import file1`? In my case I use `sys.path.append("../")` and then `import module1.file1`.

Answer (score 0):

This is very confusing and if you are using IDE like [PyCharm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JetBrains#IDEs), it's little more confusing.

What worked for me:

1. Make PyCharm project settings (if you are running Python from a [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) or from Python directory)
2. There is nothing wrong with the way you defined. Sometime it works with:

   ```py
   from folder1.file1 import class
   ```

   If it does not work, use:

   ```py
   import folder1.file1
   ```
3. Your environment variable should be correctly mentioned in system or provide it in your command-line argument.

Answer (score 0):

#### Let's say you DON'T want to do any of these:

- run with `python -m pkg.tests.core_test`
- edit `__package__`
- add `if` check in `__main__`
- edit `sys.path` by hand
- restructure the project

#### Here is what you can do instead:

`$ pip install importmonkey` [[github](https://github.com/hirsimaki-markus/importmonkey)] [[pip](https://pypi.org/project/importmonkey/)] [[docs](https://github.com/hirsimaki-markus/importmonkey/blob/b57ffc7412eda20f8820e30bf27c2ccc309d389d/src/importmonkey/__init__.py#L25C49-L25C49)]

```
├─ src
│   └─ project
│       ├─ __init__.py
│       └─ module.py
└─ test
    └─ test.py
```

```py
# In test.py

from importmonkey import add_path
add_path("../src")  # relative to current __file__
import project
```

Answer (score -2):

Because your code contains `if __name__ == "__main__"`, which doesn't be imported as a package, you'd better use `sys.path.append()` to solve the problem.

Comment: I don't think having `if __name__ == "__main__"` in your file makes a difference to anything related to importing.